# App crashing on versions lower then Nougat

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an android app which works perfectly on nougat but when I ran it on lower versions i.e. 4 , 5 and 6 it doesn't load at all even in debugging when the activity gets launched it immediately gets crashed I generated signed apk and the same runs well on nougat but in versions lower then nougat after installing the apk as soon as I press open it gets crashed with message 'Unfortunately Stopped'

the following is the loagcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: eelam.ellalan.rechargemafia, PID: 31814
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eelam.ellalan.rechargemafia/eelam.ellalan.rechargemafia.SplashActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2590)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                                                       at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:605)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3774)
                                                       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:150)
                                                       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:94)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:89)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: Add you style for `SplashActivity`.

Comment: @Nilu It Solved my problem in a moment Thanks for your help

Comment: @Varshil happy to help you enjoy codding